# Django and Websockets: How to create, in the same process, an efficient project with both WSGI and websockets?

Tags: django, websocket, twisted, tornado

I'm trying to do a Django application with an asynchronous part: Websockets. Just as a little challenge, I want to mount everything in the same process. Tried Socket.IO but couldn't manage to actually use sockets, instead of longpolling (which killed my browser several times, until I gave up).

What I then tried was a not-so-maintained library based on gevent-websocket. However, had many errors and was not easy to debug.

Now I am trying a Tornado approach but AFAIK (please correct me if I'm wrong) integrating async with a regular django app wrapped by WSGIContainer (websockets would go through Tornado, regular connections through Django) will be a true server killer if a resource is heavy or, somehow, the Django ORM goes slow into heavy operations.

I was thinking on moving to Twisted/Cyclone. Before I move from one architecture with such issue to ANOTHER architecture with such issue, i'd like to ask:

**Does Tornado (and/or Twisted) have an architecture of scheduling tasks in the same way Gevent does?** (this means: when certain greenlets "block", they schedule themselves to other threads, at least until the operation finishes). I'm asking this because (please correct me if I'm wrong) a regular django view will not be suitable for stuff like `@inlineCallbacks`, and will cause the whole server to be blocked (incl. the websockets).

I'm new to async programming in python, so there's a huge change I have misinformation about more than one concept. Please help me clarifying this before I switch.

Comment: +1 for very intesreting topic. It's not that obvious today what is/are the right way(s) to deal with websockets in Django.

Comment: From my viewpoint, its a nightmare. When I thought that I found the perfect architecture (in a blog article), then I learned that Tornado does not support something like greenlets out of the box, and making a WSGI request (Django WSGI requests are a bit heavy, and for some purposes they should be, althought they could be seriously improved) would block the whole server. Don't know what to do xDDDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Tornado nor Twisted have anything like gevent's magic to run (some) blocking code with the performance characteristics of asynchronous code. Idiomatic use of either Tornado or Twisted will be visible throughout your app in the form of callbacks and/or Futures/Deferreds.

In general, since you'll need to run multiple python processes anyway due to the GIL, it's usually best to dedicate some processes to websockets with Tornado/Twisted and other processes to Django with the WSGI container of your choice (and then put nginx or haproxy in front so it looks like a single service to the outside world).

If you still want to combine django and an asynchronous service in the same process, the next best solution is to use threads. If you want the two to share one listening port, the listener must be a websocket-aware HTTP server that can spawn other threads for WSGI requests. Tornado does not yet have a solution for this, although one is planned for version 4.1 (https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/pull/1075). I believe Twisted's WSGI container does support running the WSGI workers in threads, but I don't have any experience with it myself. If you need them in the same process but do not need to share the same port, then you can simply run the IOLoop or Reactor in one thread and the WSGI container of your choice in another (with its associated worker threads).

Comment: I will go for that. Was the next in order of preference. Thanks :D (Hope such pull/1075 end with some sort of magic like the one I was asking, rather than threads). A pity a solution like the one I was asking does not exist yet :(.